# How to create fingerprint login without using fingerprint capture device?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there possible to use fingerprint image to replace the image generated from the fingerprint device? My requirement is

1. Need to Use SDK
2. Use VB languages
3. Without Fingerprint device

Please give suggestion so I can start my process. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched for fingerprint verification sdk's? There is for instance a [VeriFinger SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html).

Comment: there is some free sdk to download but not work for window 7. So far the sdk support window vista only. Thank alot griegs^^

Comment: @Calvin: The SDK is officially supported on Windows 7. What particular problem have you had?